# unable to use graphics card after upgrading driver

Tags: windows-7, nvidia-graphics-card

I am using the following:
- Windows 7 64 bit
- Gigabyte Z87-HD3 motherboard
- Nvidia GTX 750 Ti graphics card

Things were working fine until I upgraded the graphics card so that it had a newer CUDA version. Once I updated the drivers Windows is not able to use the graphics card (or unwilling to). Instead, Windows starts on the dedicated card, as per the BIOS setting (i.e. "starting windows" screen) but at the login, switches to the integrated intel card.

In the device manager, the driver is reported as being fine. I am able to make CUDA calls to it as well. The windows "display - screen resolution" screen sees the monitor but I am unable to activate the monitor.

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling the driver. This includes using DDU as well as the clean installation options. Any suggestions on how to get Windows to output to the graphics card?

Regarding the driver version. I tried updating to 376.33. My previous version was 340.52. I ran into this problem before (2 years ago?) and reverted. I need to update the driver so that I can use a program that requires a newer version of CUDA (>7.5).

dxdiag is only showing the intel integrated graphics when I run it ...

Comment: So I presume, when you rolled back to the prevous version of the driver, the behavior you describe went away?

Comment: Can you provide your dxdiag report?  What version of the Intel driver do you have?  What version of the Nvidia driver worked?  What version of the Nvidia driver didn't work.  You should edit your question to include this information.

Comment: @Ramhound I just uninstalled the driver and reinstalled the driver from the original installation cds. It is still not working. I think to fix this last time (2 years ago)I had to reinstall the operating system :/ I'd obviously prefer not to do that again.

Answer (score 0):

So ... I ended deciding to try updating to Windows 10 to see if it would help. Contrary to most things breaking when you update to Windows 10, upgrading fixed the problem.

What I still have yet to see an explanation anywhere on is how the driver could have been working (according to the device manager), how I could communicate with it (via CUDA calls), and yet Windows would not display to it. Part of me thinks the solution might have been with some incorrect registry setting that I hadn't eliminated.

Comment: The simplest answer is that the problem was caused by a WDDM version conflict.  The fact upgrading to the current feature update which has a different WDDM version then the feature update you were using.

Answer (score -2):

Install all updates for your Windows and BIOS.
Uninstall all drivers for the card. 
Reboot
Reinstall the driver you wish to run (the one with a newer CUDA version)
test.

If still not working install the latest fully working driver that you have been using prior to this, and watch for new updates for the card that may resolve this issue.

The notice that the device/driver is working in device manager can only show the current build of windows understanding of the driver.  sometimes the operating system believes it is working properly with a driver because there is no error for it to process differently.  Ive seen hundreds of devices that show fine in the device manager but have some of all functionality not working entirely properly.  The most common reason that i have found is that windows is missing an update that added (or removed is some cases) the way something is handled or the ability of a process.

an analogy: if you could only use words from a small translator book for traveling abroad to speak your own language it would sort of work and also sometimes not as well.  but when you upgraded to a full dictionary of words from your language you would be able to more easily communicate more complex things.
Sometimes an update adds a better way to communicate with devices, this would only effect devices whose drivers also utilize the new libraries ect.
Most likely in your case it is an existing library and thats why it sort of works, but an update (which i understand you were against) added a little to that existing library.

Windows updates have had a bumpy ride for windows 10, however the newer updates have been more stable in my experience across a few thousand devices i work with.